# What does "duck an exception" mean?

Tags: java, exception, terminology

In the [Advantages of Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html) section of the Java™ tutorials:

> A method can duck any exceptions thrown within it, thereby allowing a method farther up the call stack to catch it.
>
> [...]
>
> ...ducking an exception requires some effort on the part of the middleman methods. Any checked exceptions that can be thrown within a method must be specified in its `throws` clause.

What does "duck an exception" mean here?  I searched the web and FOLDOC (Free On-line Dictionary of Computing) but didn't find anything that looked promising.

Comment: From the pseudo code shown in the tutorial, I would say it means not to catch the exception in the method itself, but ignore it (and in case of checked exceptions add it to the `throws` clause) so that it can be catched by a method further up in the call stack

Comment: "duck" in this context means forwarding the exception to the caller.

Comment: well... DUCK simply means to lower your head in order to avoid being hit or seen. For your method not to be hit by exception, you THROW it further up the call stack by declaring a `throws` exception on your method

Comment: What is it with all these questions about ducks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To "duck an exception" means "not handle the exception". This actually explains the name: [to duck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duck) means to "To evade; dodge".

The method ducking the exception simply doesn't handle it (because, for example, it is not its purpose) and let the exception be thrown to the calling method.

For example, consider a method whose purpose is to count the number of lines in a file. This would be a simple implementation (Java 8):

```
private static long numberOfLines(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        return br.lines().count();
    }
}
```

Note that this method doesn't handle the `IOException` that is thrown by `Files.newBufferedReader(path)`, because that's not the method goal. It ducks and let the caller handle it appropriately.

Note the caller might also duck the exception and let *its* caller handle it, etc.

Answer (score 29):

Well, ducking simply means to lower your head in order to avoid being hit or seen. In this case, 'duck an exception' just means avoiding your code from getting hit by an exception.

For your method not to be hit by exception, you throw it further up the call stack by declaring a `throws` exception on your method

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {

}
```

If you don't duck, you have to `catch` it:

```
public void myMethod() {
    try {
       // ...  

    } catch(IOException e) {
      // handle exception
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, since Java does not provide a way for an exception to hit a method in the face, these are the only two options.

Comment: @Elogent `try { someCheckedExceptionHere(); } catch (SomeCheckedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }` I do this quite frequently when I need to handle a checked exception and it occurring should result in an application crash (e.g. failure to load an FXML file describing a JavaFX scene required to start the application).

Answer (score 5):

i think it means a method can catch an exception and re-throw it for other method to catch it and handle it as needed. Or just throw a new exception. Or avoid catching an exception and let it bubble up the call stack. The point is to have a method **delegate exception handling** to other method which might be more appropriate to handle a given exception (e.g by having access to necessary data and/or state). But (for `java`) this requires declaring methods with `throws` clause all the time, which becomes boilerplate easily

as mentioned in @jmcg's comment, literally "*DUCK simply means to lower your head in order to avoid being hit or seen*" (like ducks do in a river)

Comment: I don't think ducking means to catch and rethrow. The part "Or avoid catching" sounds right, but the 2 sentences previous are perhaps incorrect.

Comment: @vikingsteve, maybe so, but still it is about delegation, a method can indeed catch an exception to do some things and re-throw it to delegate for rest. Added for completeness

Comment: Well you have explained a few cases but i dont think you are really answering the question - it's quite specific: "duck" an exception. If it has said "handle" an exception then I think the cases you describe would be more valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think to duck means re-throw an exception... in other words, ignore it hoping that someone else will handle it :)